# GitLab job fails due to "bad decrypt" OpenSSL error, but the command executes just fine locally?

Tags: encryption, openssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Having a pipeline with a stage that executes a script that is supposed to decrypt a key file, the GitLab Runner fails:

```
$ scripts/decrypt.sh $LWCMAP_SERVER_KEY
bad decrypt
139810674749504:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:536:
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The `$LWCMAP_SERVER_KEY` contains a passphrase that is used to decrypt the key inside a folder, using the following command in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
- scripts/decrypt.sh $LWCMAP_SERVER_KEY
```

And the content of the shell script is just the OpenSSL command to decrypt the file:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -k $1 -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/decripted_server.key -d
```

---

I wonder why the job fails with "bad decrypt" since the exact same command executes just fine locally. I even calculated the md5 of both the file and the key used on decryption, and they are the exact same on the runner and locally (which means it is not corrupted data).

Any ideas?

Edit:

Locally `openssl version` outputs "LibreSSL 2.8.3", and on the server, I upgraded it to the same version. On the Runner's container though, the output is "OpenSSL 1.1.0j 20 Nov 2018".

Comment: Just when I thought I'd finally seen a solution, no answers :-(

Answer (score 1):

So I think I figured why, and what to do to fix..
It does seem like LibreSSL 2.8x is incompatible with OpenSSL 1.1x.

This means that files encrypted on one TLS implementation is unable to decrypt with the other.

What I did instead, was to `ssh` into the Ubuntu VM then run the encryption there. Since the CI is going to be run with any of our Ubuntu VMs and will be deployed on similar machines using similar TLS implementations, I do not anticipate any further problems with key file encryption/decryption.

This means that I would be unable to test decrypt on my local machine though, but I'm sure I can live with that :-)